# Python hosts file entries in memory

Tags: python, hosts

i have some scripts that use a hardcoded FQDN. I am not allowed to change the scripts because of very specific reasons that i can not elaborate on.
These scripts rely on an entry in the hosts file in windows.

However, i want to be able to control multiple devices with those scripts without having to change the IP value of that FQDN in the hosts file each time.
So i wrote a python script to visualize the commands that those scripts implement.
Via that python script i want to be able to change the ip value for that FQDN by specifying the ip address in a textfield in the python program.
Instead of running the python program with administrative rights and parsing/updating the hosts file each time, can't i change the FQDN ip in memory?

I would like your thoughts.
Please don't suggest to change the underlying scripts because that is no option.
the scripts also don't take ip parameters.

i hope this makes sence.

so:

-- hosts file

---- business logic scripts that rely on hosts file

------ Python program that wraps a visual layer over the business logic scripts. Here i want to specify the ip address via a textbox.

Comment: Which OS is this? For Linux, you can find solutions (such as HOSTALIASES) here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6887/can-i-create-override-dns-similar-to-writing-in-etc-hosts-without-root-access

Comment: unfortunately for windows

Comment: The FQDN's IP isn't going to be in *your* process's memory, if it's in memory at all at a given point in time it's going to be inside some component of the operating system, that you cannot possibly get to.

Comment: Is there a windows alternative to linux's HOSTALIASES ?